# Child Process Executing Print Statement But Nothing Afterwards

Tags: c, fork, stdout

I have the following code:

```
    pid_t childProcessID;

    childProcessID = fork();

    if (childProcessID == -1) {
            printf("fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (childProcessID == 0) {
            printf("reached child\n");
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);

            printf("about to execute child command\n");
            if (fork() == 0) {
                    execve(argv1[0], argv1, NULL);
                    printf("Command not found.");
                    exit(1);
            }
            else {
                    wait(NULL);
            }
    }
    else {
            printf("reached parent, but wait for child to finish\n");
            waitpid(childProcessID, &child_status, NULL);
            printf("child finished\n");

            close(STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            close(fd[1]);

            printf("About to executed piped command\n");
            if (fork() == 0) {
                    execve(argv2[0], argv2, NULL);
                    printf("Command not found");
                    exit(1);
            }
            else {
                    wait(NULL);
            }
    }
```

When I run my minishell and give it the input nl parse.c | wc -l, My minishell prints out:

reached parent, but wait for child to finish

reached child

And nothing underneath. The program is clearly still running but nothing is being printed. Why is my child not executing the rest of the code? argv1[] and argv[2] are initialized and work fine.

Comment: You closed `STDOUT`, then you `printf` to closed STDOUT - so, where this `printf` result have to be visible?

Comment: The implementation of `forkpty()` and `openpty()` in musl libc source code may help.

Comment: Remove all your closing and dup of the fds and then try again. Then read the documentation and check return values.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("fork failed");` In general, always end the format string with `\n'.  However, error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`,  This can be done with `fprintf( stderr, "error message\n" );`  However, when the error is from a C library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  This is easiest done with the function: `perror( "error message" );`

Comment: The file descriptor number needs to point to an open file.  So these two lines: `close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);` need to be in the reverse order.

Comment: before the end of this code block: `if (childProcessID == 0) {` need to call `exit()` so the child process properly exits

Comment: regarding: `dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);`  the posted code never creates a pipe nor uses a pipe, so these three statements can be eliminated

Comment: so we do not have to guess about your code, please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

When you do :

```
dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO)
```

This code tells the process to redirect its `STDOUT: Standard Output`, i.e. the print commands and everything that gets printed on terminal to file descriptor `fd[1]`.

So your child process executes and prints everything as it is supposed to,but not on the terminal. To see the output on terminal, comment the line :

```
//dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it printed /bin/nl: write error: Bad file descriptor and then nothing else afterwards

Comment: Hey @jimmyjohns242, Comment all the following lines: 
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);